# Unit-testing a timezone based logic

Tags: unit-testing, timezone

The America/New_York timezone is called EST in winter and EDT(in summer). Now my java program has a page that displays current time with the time zone as EDT.

To test the winter scenario, is there any way to manipulate the computer settings to simulate a winter scenario? Just to see if for a winter time, it displays EST proeprly?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency inject the current time by passing it into your display.

Answer (score 0):

For unittesting its not recommended to manipulate the system datetime, there are some workarounds to test date time based logic part.

Take alook at these threads:

- [Unit testing time-based logic in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410046/unit-testing-time-based-logic-in-java)
- [How do I write unit tests to make sure my date/time based code works for all time zones and with/out DST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846704/how-do-i-write-unit-tests-to-make-sure-my-date-time-based-code-works-for-all-tim)